# How to create AWS IAM policy that allows user to create only RDS aurora serverless instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-aurora-serverless

I want to allows IAM users to create only Aurora Serverless instance with specific minimum and maximum aurora capacity units. Is there any way to do it? In policy condition I can only set database engine:

```
{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "rds:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "rds:DatabaseEngine": "aurora-postgresql"
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be a case of governance over-reach into configuration. You might instead want to consider using the CloudWatch *ServerlessDatabaseCapacity* metric to trigger mitigation.

Comment: Wouldn't `ServerlessDatabaseCapacity` only trigger when a serverless instance has been created? The question is about preventing non-serverless instances from being created.

Comment: I am imagining a use case that primarily concerns long-term costs. If it is not possible to limit capacity through policy constraints, then the next best scenario is to - for example - automatically delete or alter any database shortly after it was created with incorrect constraints.